# Как добавить класс в тег хтмл при скроле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно сделать шапку, как на этом шаблоне: http://demo.hashthemes.com/square/.
Чтобы при скролле в тег `header` добавлялся класс, который заменит фон шапки.

Comment: Не знаете - на фриланс.

Comment: при скроле менять css , это же просто !

Answer (score 3):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset,
      obj_cap = document.querySelector('.cap');
  
  if( scrollTop >= 100 ){
    obj_cap.classList.add('cap__bg--all');
  }else{
    obj_cap.classList.remove('cap__bg--all');
  };
};
```

```css
body {height: 1000px;}

.cap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.cap__bg--all {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="cap">Наша шапочка :3</div>
```

Comment: Хватить фармить репу на таких вопросах! Вы же поощряете других превращать SO в бесплатный фриланс.

Comment: Спасибо. Но у меня не работает. Не могу понять почему. Классы свои подставил...

Comment: @димаовчаров, можете где-то показать, как вы добавили?

Comment: @Yuri, скрин -> http://radikal.ru/big/qpkb19ceyl9ab

Comment: @димаовчаров, а вы класс `cap__bg--all` в CSS прописали?

Comment: @Yuri, да, прописал

Comment: @димаовчаров, покажите. А консоль что-то пишет?

Comment: @димаовчаров, а ещё проверьте путь к JS файлу, на всякий случай :)

Comment: @Yuri, http://i045.radikal.ru/1703/3a/c3f5a79cca36.png , с путём всё в порядке

Comment: @димаовчаров, а попробуйте `.cap__bg--all {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) !important;
}` написать, или `.header.cap__bg--all {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}`

Comment: @Yuri, ничего не помогло)

Comment: @димаовчаров, залейте свой ваш код на jsfiddle и покажите ссылку :) У вас там явно где-то что-то не так

Comment: @Yuri, https://jsfiddle.net/y35zryou/

Comment: @димаовчаров, так всё работает... https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/y35zryou/1/

Comment: @димаовчаров, у вас скролл вообще есть на сайте? Ну что бы прокрутка была

Comment: @Yuri `obj_cap = document.querySelector('.cap')` - лучше вынести из обработчика.

Comment: @Yuri , да, прокрутка есть...

Comment: подключено тоже верно http://s001.radikal.ru/i193/1703/d8/0b8ee4ba6b80.png
скрипт и хтмл в одном каталоге лежат

Comment: @димаовчаров, тогда не знаю. Тут же работает. Значит у вас где-то ошибка